# Can Optunity be used in Multi class svm?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, optunity

I ran a program with optunity to find the hyperparameter of SVM without deciding the kernel first as seen here http://optunity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebooks/notebooks/sklearn-svc.html#tune-svc-without-deciding-the-kernel-in-advance it ran but when i replaced the data and labels with multi class information it commits an error how come this is hapenning.

Answer (score 1):

Optunity uses ROC-AUC for selecting optimum hyper parameters. AUC can't be estimated for multiclass problems. Some workaround solutions for using Optunity for multiclass problems are:

1. Use Accuracy as criterian for selecting optimum parameters rather than AUC
2. Convert multiclass into binary class and select optimum parameters for each classifier.